# Not able to access HDFS from the Datanodes in clusture

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Have installed cloudera cdh4 on 3 node cluster.Facing problem when trying to access the data in HDFS through slave nodes(Datanodes).

When I am  trying to create the new folder in HDFS using

> hadoop fs -mkdir Flume(Foldername)

command not able to put the data or create the folder in the hdfs of the cluster from either of the slaves,but working from the master node,also flume ,hive ,pig all other process are running in the slaves
(Datanodes)
Tried 
restarting the cluster 
namenode format
Still not working!!

Secondly When I am doing

> hadoop fs -ls /

results are not of from the hdfs but from the current directory path of the slave node from where I am usin this command.
And how to check if hdfs is working and installed properly in slave nodes(Datanodes) in cluster apart from creating the directory in HDFS.
Could anybody help?

Comment: What is your value of `fs.default.name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify the property "fs.default.name" in the core-site.xml.

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://namenode:9000</value>
</property>
```